# Trying to click on button outside <form> tag in selenium webdriver with Submit() method

Tags: selenium, webdriver, submit

While clicking on button which is outside form tag using submit() of selenium webdriver getting org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException instead of NoSuchElementException(as per the documentation) If the given element is not within a form

following is the code

```
public void setup() {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    System.out.println("Execution Starts");
    // Setting chrome driver property and opening chrome browser
    System.out.println("Browser opened.");
    // We need to downcast WebDriver reference varaible to use JavascriptExecutor methods
    
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      // identify elements
      driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/");
      // submitting form with click()
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ytd-button-renderer[@class='style-scope ytd-masthead style-default size-default']//yt-icon[@class='style-scope ytd-button-renderer']")).submit();
}
```

Comment: Use click() instead of submit() if it is not a form button.

Comment: .submit() must be used on an element which is inside the form.  (Otherwise it can't find the form you need to submit...)  Also seems to be changed in Selenium v4... look at the bottom of this page: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/interactions/